# Converting JSON objects in to dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

I have string of data basically which has a objects with in the objects..

```
{"id":"XXXX", "name": "xyz", "user" : { "id": "XXXX", "username":"XYZ", group:{"id": "XXXX"}}}. You can check this format using "http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.html" site.
```

No my requirement is to convert this to JSON objects as a dictionary. I have tried below way

```
import json
JSON_Datalist = '{"id":"XXXX", "name": "xyz", "user" : { "id": "XXXX", "username":"XYZ", group:{"id": "XXXX"}}}'
the_dict = json.loads(JSON_DataList)
```

but the_dict gives only left side values, no right values...

In the same way if string has a format..

```
"[{"sample": false, "radop": null, "view": true, "Example1": null}, {"noMarket": false, "Example2": null}]"
```

and following the same code.

```
JSON_Datalist = '[{"sample": false, "radop": null, "view": true, "Example1": null}, {"noMarket": false, "Example2": null}]'

the_dict = json.loads(JSON_DataList)
```

it gives the dictionary of length of 2, and this is what expected...

Can any please help me out in first case how can I get a dictionary...

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. `group` needs to be quoted.

Comment: protip: If you want valid JSON, do something like this: `import json; json.dumps({'key': 'val', 'other_key' : {'something': [1, 2, 3]}})` - let the `json` library do it for you.

Answer (score 8):

I found two errors in your first example:

1. You have a `group` in your stringified (Json) version of your dict.  This should be a `"group"` (with quotes).
2. You misspelled your variable; `JSON_Datalist` ≠ `JSON_DataList` (lowercase vs. capital L).

After fixing both, I had no problems anymore:

```
>>> JSON_Datalist = '{"id":"XXXX", "name": "xyz", "user" : { "id": "XXXX", "username":"XYZ", "group":{"id": "XXXX"}}}'
>>> the_dict = json.loads(JSON_Datalist)
>>> the_dict
{u'user': {u'username': u'XYZ', u'group': {u'id': u'XXXX'}, u'id': u'XXXX'}, u'id': u'XXXX', u'name': u'xyz'}
```

Comment: Thanks Alfe,  Now I want get the value of "id": "XXXX" which is present in user: group how to get this?, In Python we can get the value like this the_dict['user']['group']['id'], this will print ID value. How to do this in program

Comment: What do you mean when you mention a difference between "in Python" and "in program"?  Just use `the_dict['user']['group']['id']` as you proposed.  What's the issue with using this?

Comment: Thanks..I know the_dict['user']['group']['id'] will give the value, but it is static interpreter command. In run time I don't know the exact command (which key value). EX: it may be dict['user'] or dict['user']['group'] or dict['user']['group']['id']['etc..']['etc..']. So can you suggest me on this case how can I make this interpreter command on run time.

Comment: To be elaborate: Say I have function fun1(), which has JSON_Datalist dictionary.. from python I will call this function by key names to get the value. Say I will call the function as fun1(user:group) to get the values. Here the argument can any deep level.

Comment: I understand (I think).  Please explain how the wanted value is specified.  Is it a (the only) leaf in the tree which fits a certain condition?  What is this condition?  To perform a search in a tree you can use breadth-search or depth-search or a more custom-tailored variant.  But I need to know more about the situation you are in to give qualified advice.

Answer (score 5):

after fix the problem group should be "group", below code can meet your requirement

```
json_data={"id":"XXXX", "name": "xyz", "user" : { "id": "XXXX", "username":"XYZ", "group":{"id": "XXXX"}}}
data = json.dumps(json_data)
json_to_python = json.loads(data)
print (json_to_python)


{'id': 'XXXX', 'name': 'xyz', 'user': {'id': 'XXXX', 'username': 'XYZ', 'group': {'id': 'XXXX'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to generate `the_dict['user']['group']['id']` dynamically through Python's `eval` expression.

*Keys* is the input from the user, separated by `:`. Example: `user:group:id`.

**CODE:**

```
RefCount = 0
RespDict = json.loads(JSON_Datalist.content) #convert strings to Java object using JSON
SplitKeys = Keys.split(":") 
KeyCount = len(SplitKeys)
CommandText = "RespDict" #To setup command line based on keys information
while (RefCount <KeyCount):
    CommandText = CommandText+"['"+SplitKeys[RefCount]+"']"
    RefCount = RefCount + 1
    print CommandText        
print eval(CommandText)  #Final key value
```