# Sort python dictionary for keys, split it and create a JSON Array from it

Tags: python, json, sorting, dictionary

I have this huge JSON file, which contains more than 80000 lines, looking like that:

```
{u'hero_name': u'bristleback', u'gold_total': 17937, tick:24098}
{u'hero_name': u'silencer', u'gold_total': 10847, tick:24198}
{u'hero_name': u'silencer', u'gold_total': 11789, tick:25098}
{u'hero_name': u'weaver', u'gold_total': 27084, tick:27098}
```

There are 10 different heroes with their gold data. I want to sort that data for the hero names, make a json list of the gold data, and then store it in a databse table looking like that, where gold_data should be like [{tick, gold}, {tick, gold}, ...]

```
id | hero_name | gold_data (json field) | ...
```

But seems like i am too stupid to sort that. I tried building a list out of it and using `sorted(gold_list, key=lambda s: s[0])`

I am just not too comfortable with Python yet and I tried so many different things, but i have no idea how to sort,and then split this dictionary for the hero_names key so I can get that JSON object for gold_data

Comment: Have you tried using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: Well i am receiving Json, convert it to a dict so i can work with it and then convert it back to json.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. Python has built-in functionality for handling JSON, as linked above, so please look into it and make an effort to use it. Then, if you're still stuck, you'll have an actual [mcve]. And please don't put noise like thank yous in your posts; I edited it out for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) - there are other packages, but this one should do it.

1. Load the JSON to a veriable using `open()`
2. Convert to `dict` using `json.loads()`

For example:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

dct = json.loads(data)
pprint(dct)
```

You CANNOT sort the dictionary though - you will have to convert the `dict` to **array of tuples** - [please, refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110407/converting-json-objects-in-to-dictionary-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)